# Is there any poll interval setting for the self-hosted integration runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I use a combination of lookup and foreach activities to iterate through the set of data ingestion queries and execute them (reasons behind that is a separate broad topic :)). As the data source is connected to the private network, I have provisioned a dedicated VM to run the self-hosted runtime. In most cases everything runs smoothly, I can see worker processes eating the CPU and high overall CPU utilization (which is good).

**But:** sometimes, when most work is done, and there are just 2-3 activities standing in line, I can see that the runtime does no processing and CPU usage drops to zero, no new entries appear in the event log. After some time (approximately 10 minutes) I get the 30002 (the example is provided below) and runtime happily completes the work.

Example event message:

```
Job ID: ***-fcab-429a-bb45-***
Task ID: ***-d820-414e-ad8c-***
Queue ID: ***-4f44-4c39-a1c1-***
Log ID: PulledOffNewTask
```

**The question**: What could be the root cause of such Azure Data Factory self-hosted integration runtime's behaviour? Can this be fine-tuned?

---

#### UPDATE 1

Errors have been spotted in the application log and warnings have been spotted in the integration runtime log.

Application log contains 3 sets of errors (see below events [1] to [5]) that occured in the time interval of ~2 minutes, shortly after that 8 events (exactly the number of my worker processes) were logged to the integration runtime log (see [6]), straight after that "Windows Error Reporting" events appear. And then we face a "freeze".

So - looks like a bug :(

**"application"** log:

[1]

```
Application: diawp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.CopyTaskBase.UpdateJobProgress(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

[2]

```
Faulting application name: diawp.exe, version: 3.5.6639.1, time stamp: 0x5aa8cf5f
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00007ff914402c65
Faulting process id: 0x1bc4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3d287ef6e34fa
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\3.0\Shared\diawp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 1fe7de4d-5481-478d-b9e7-d542c24ab18a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

[3]: Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

[4]: The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available.

**"Integration Runtime"** log:

[6]

```
'Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=Instance &apos;diawp#10&apos; does not exist in the specified Category.,Source=System,StackTrace=   at System.Diagnostics.CounterDefinitionSample.GetInstanceValue(String instanceName)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.FormatedPerfCounter.TryGet(Single&amp; value),'
Job ID: 7b629411-c6cd-42d0-9939-e830e58db015
Log ID: Warning
```

Comment: If you can show this in the logs, then report it to Microsoft as a support issue (bug).

Comment: we fixed this error in next IR release, you can have a try when it is ready on download center. Thanks for report to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like caused by worker crash. Could you please check event log from: Windows Log => Application? Any error in the category?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't have a lot of options to tune the Integration Runtime. My bet is a connectivity issue with your private network. Whenever you run the pipeline, open a cmd at the vm and ping the database pc with -t. If the process hangs, take a look at the response time between pings.

Example ping:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

30002 means IntegrationRuntime got new tasks assigned and started execution.
If the 10 minutes "retry interval" could constantly be reproduced, then 30002 could further indicate that IntegrationRuntime lost tracks on the previous failed tasks it got assigned and had to go with retry.

You can search the specific JobIds in the eventlogs to verify whether shown up 10 minutes before and any exceptions related to.

Btw, the polling interval in normal happy path is in seconds level.

Comment: There are actually no retries in my case. My setup includes 2 pipelines - the "outer" one triggers approx. 10 concurrent executions of "inner" one (via foreach). Each instance of the "inner" pipeline spins off 9 concurrent copy activities (via foreach as well).
So 87 of 90 happily line up and picked up with no delays, whilst remaining 3 (or 2, or 5 - depends on stars :)) may be picked up after that 10 minutes delay.

Comment: Just like I said, IntegrationRuntime crashes turned the Tasks into "Lost track", and a 10 minutes retry logic inside IR guaranteed that your pipeline could succeed despite of the delay. This retry is different from the notable "retry" in DataFactory Scheduler. Back to the bug, please wait for the next IR release.